# Angular 2 HTTP response returns json as number instead of decimal

Tags: json, angular, culture

I have problem with response on two different computers, on one computer api returns data (@angular/http) like:

```
{ amount: 233.55 }
```

but on other computer it returns same data like:

```
{ amount: 23355 }
```

so it ignores ".". This looks like culture problem, is there way to set culture to return same json like in first example?

Comment: Check the raw server response. It's very unlikely this has anything to do with Angular

Comment: Thanks @martin, it looks like servers were on different cultures!